# How do I put a graph inside my glance widget I have made with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, widget, android-jetpack-compose, glance

I have made a glance widget with jetpack compose that I want to use outside the app. I managed to make it work using strings or integers but I can't find a chart that is compatible with my widget. Everytime I try using a chart it gives me the following track trace.

Error in Glance App Widget
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalDensity not present at.........

The error is also explained in here https://proandroiddev.com/first-steps-with-glance-app-widgets-b1e28e25a107

The problem is that the library that the widget uses which is named glance is only compatible with "objects" that only use the same library (glance)

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.